# I use kartik widget(ExportMenu) in Yii2. But I have very much data. I can not download data. help to find alternative variation ExportMenu

Tags: yii2, export-to-excel

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
                    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
                    'columns' => $gridColumns,
                ]);
```

please help to find alternative export menu

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try with batch export. See the link or example below - https://demos.krajee.com/export-demo-dtl/batch-loading

```
echo ExportMenu::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => $gridColumns,
    'batchSize' => 10,
    'target' => '_blank',
])
```